# "Identity Toolkit for Websites" vs. "Identity Toolkit for Websites v2" (August 2015)

Tags: javascript, documentation, google-identity-toolkit

While googling for "[google identity toolkit javascript](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20identity%20toolkit%20javascript&hl=en)" I noticed that there are two versions avaliable.

[Products►Google Identity Platform►Identity Toolkit►Identity Toolkit for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/)

[Products►Google Identity Platform►Identity Toolkit►Identity Toolkit for Websites v2](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v2/getting_started)

If one starts at [Products►Google Identity Platform►Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/) there's no way to get to v2, as everything is referencing v1 without mentioning v2.

- So, what's up with v2?
- Should new projects use v2?

Additionally, when starting from [Products►Google Identity Platform►Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/) there's no way to get to the other "variant" of the v1 documentation, the one located [at this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v1/getting_started) which offers information very similar to v2 (Getting Started page) and possibly is the actual documentation for the "Identity Toolkit for Websites".

Also, when one then compares the v1 to the almost identical v2 documentation, one may notice that the use of the word "GITkit" has been replaced by "Identity Toolkit":

v1:

> **[Introduction to Federated Login and Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v1/openid)**
>
> Google Identity Toolkit (GITkit) enables the Relying Parties to use internet
>   standard protocols, OpenID 2.0 and OAuth, to verify that a user owns
>   an account on their web sites

v2:

> **[Introduction to Federated Login and [Google]* Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v2/openid)**
>
> Google Identity Toolkit (Identity Toolkit) enables the Relying Parties
>   to use internet standard protocols, OpenID 2.0 and OAuth, to verify
>   that a user owns an account on their web sites

- I've placed Google in square brackets because while the title contains the word, the left side menu entry doesn't.

What's the reason for this transistion? This only a refactoring effort in the documentation (and possisbly in the libraries as well) or is the underlying technology changing and including incompatibilities between these two versions?

Is there somewhere a statement issued by Google or one of the GITkit developers who explained the roadmap, the changes across versions, the current state of the "Identity Toolkit" and the phase-out of GITkit?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the documentation for the first link corresponding to v3 which is the latest version and the one actively supported and recommended by Google. v2 is an older version with no active development.

Comment: How about adding a deprecation warning on
_https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v1/getting_started_ and _https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v2/getting_started_, possibly with a link to the latest documentation? When googling for that stuff, _Products►Google Identity Platform►Identity Toolkit_ isn't always the entry point for a developer. (I'm assuming you work for Google on this stuff, right?)